# Python mock to create a fake object returns dictionary when any of it's attribute is used

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

for example I have a method in Django which reuses the request object:

```
def dowork(request):
    # the sessionid is a query param of the callback from payment gateway
    print request.GET.get('sessionid')
```

When I write unittest, I need to create a fake request object, which should has `GET` attribute and should contains a dictionary `{'sessionid': 'blah'}`

How do I do that using the mock package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this by creating a mock, and setting its attributes like any other python object.

The only caveat is that mocks are specialized so that their attributes are automatically padded with mocks, which makes this very easy. You don't need to explicitly create each attribute as a mock object.

For example,

```
import mock
mock_request = mock.Mock()

mock_request.GET.get.return_value = {'sessionid': 'blah'}

x = mock_request.GET.get('sessionid')

assert x == {'sessionid': 'blah'}
mock_request.GET.get.assert_called_once_with('sessionid')
```

Comment: When I call `request.GET.get('sessionid')` it returns `{'sessionid': 'blah'}`, expected result should return 'blah'

Comment: OK I have worked it out based on your answer `mock_request.GET.get.return_value = 'blah'`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the built-in [test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#module-django.test.client), which supports mock sessions already?

```
def test_dowork(self):
    session = self.client.session
    session = ['sessionid'] = 'blah'
    session.save()
    response = self.client.get('/dowork/')
    self.assertEqual(...)
```

Comment: Hi the `sessionid` is a query param that comes from the callback from our credit card gateway.